# transform: translateX causes text blur

Tags: html, css

I've been going crazy about that and haven't found a solution yet, any content in the div gets blured for some reason if a `transform` is being applied.
Though this only happens in chrome.

I've tried using the Webkit style declaration : `-webkit-font-smoothing` but I didn't succeed.

The div CSS:

```
#divId {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-52%);
        transform: translateX(-52%);
}
```

below are 2 images showing the difference with and without the `transform`,
the first is with transform and the second is without the transform. thanks

[image: with transform]

[image: without transform]

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between those 2 images.

Comment: As expected the x offset of some glyphs is slightly different because of the transformation. Both images are anti-aliased, and both have similar sharpness.

Comment: @roeland Just Updated the images, you can clearly see the differences right now.

Comment: That looks like hinting has been disabled, which probably happens when you apply transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving the div without transform 
like using { position:relative;left:-52%;}
transform usually changes the quality of a text or img ( like translate or scale ) and as far as i know there is no 100% accurate work around about this